# Vkontakte Audio Search with HTTP API

Tags: vk

Sorry for my English. I know very little English.

I am trying pull data from here : http://api.vk.com/api.php?api_id=2539386&count=200&v=2.0&method=audio.search&sig=c2b83d95d3d5914de0aa6ae7ca1c1007&test_mode=1&q=beatles

c2b83d95d3d5914de0aa6ae7ca1c1007 = md5->141080534api_id=2539386count=200method=audio.searchq=beatlestest_mode=1v=2.0mysecretkey

But return to me : "Incorrect signature: ifame/flash authorization"

Where is error ?

Comment: Maybe ask the API provider? I'm not sure whether anybody here can give a canonical answer.

Comment: API provider use russian. I am not know russian.

Comment: but surely *somebody* there speaks a bit of English, don't they? They have an English version of their site, after all...

Comment: dont you need access token too?

Answer (score 1):

Should've read the API documentation first, the solution to your problem gets explained in pretty much the first line about the Audio Search method. You're getting an error because you're not authorized yet. You need to authorize your app first with rights with bitmask 8. [More info about the Audio Search method](http://vk.com/developers.php?oid=-17680044&p=audio.search) | [More info about the application rights bitmasks](http://vk.com/developers.php?oid=-17680044&p=Application_Rights)

Answer (score 1):

You are using old method my dear :) Use like this:

```
https://api.vk.com/method/audio.search.xml?access_token=TOKEN&q=QUERY
```

Replace TOKEN with your access token... Replace QUERY with your search term

[More info](http://vk.com/dev/audio.search)